# Get url params in API route handler in Next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have a client component `GetUserInfoButton`. In that component, I send a GET request on url `http://localhost:3000/test/users/[id]` where `[id]` is a MongoDb-like alphanumeric sequence.

Inside `app/api/users/[id]/route.ts`, I want to receive that request and work with that `[id]`. Here's my `GetUserInfoButton` component:

```
'use client';

export default function GetUserInfoButton({ id }: { id: string }) {
    const contentType = "application/json";
    const handleClick = async (id: string) => {
        try {
            const res = await fetch(`/api/users/${id}`, {
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": contentType,
                }
            });
            if (!res.ok) {
                throw new Error(res.status.toString());
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("error ===> ", error);
        }
    };

    return (
        <button onClick={() => handleClick(id)}>
            Get
        </button>
    );
}
```

Here's my `route.ts` file:

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET(req: NextRequest) {
    const id = req.url.split("http://localhost:3000/api/users/")[1];
    return NextResponse.json({
        success: true,
        id: id
    }, {
        status: 200,
    })
}
```

Back when it was the pages router, I could use `useRouter(`) on the client and get id on the server like this:
`const { query: { id } } = req`.

How do I get id params in server component?

I'm using  Next.js `13.4.16`.

Comment: You should be able to access it through the `params` prop, as it is described [here in the documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the [`app`](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/project-structure) directory, when you are in a dynamic route (aka the `[id]` folders), your API route handler gets passed a second object parameter which will hold your slug, as the [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers#dynamic-route-segments) shows:

```
// app/api/users/[id]/route.ts

import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET(req: NextRequest, { params }: { params: { id: string } }) {
  console.log(params.id);
  return NextResponse.json({ msg: "Hello World" });
}
```

And here is the version without types:

```js
// app/api/users/[id]/route.js

import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET(req, { params }) {
  console.log(params.id);
  return NextResponse.json({ msg: "Hello World" });
}
```

For future readers, you can get query strings (aka the `?search=value`) this way:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET(req) {
  const { searchParams } = new URL(req.url);
  console.log(searchParams.get("search"));
  return NextResponse.json({ msg: "Hello World" });
}
```

Comment: Does above syntax also works for PUT and DELETE methods ? I am using same code to read param "id" from url but getting "405 - method not found" error

Comment: Yeah it would work, but then the signature should be `export async function PUT(req, { params })` or  `export async function DELETE(req, { params })`.  You can add them below your `GET `.

Comment: Yes, it worked, I was getting 405 error because I was trying that code in "/users" instead of "/usres/[id]" routes files....my bad