# Next js Api routing

Tags: rest, next.js, backend

I am working with Next js 13.4 and trying to send id of a product with query parameters as -
http://localhost:3000/api/abc/abc/update/89?id=2

The code i wrote-

```
export async function PUT(req,res){
  console.log(req.query);
  return NextResponse.json('hi');
}
```

I am getting response perfectly but I want to log id from url and I tried using - const {id} = req.query but it shows cannot destructure id as it is undefined. Is there any way I can get that id? Without splitting the url. Main thing is I want to know why req.query is giving undefined? It should give 2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get url params in API route handler in Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76974324/get-url-params-in-api-route-handler-in-next-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Route handlers in the App router function differently compared to the previous pages API.

You've written:

```js
export async function PUT(req, res) {
```

Note that the second parameter should be the [context](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route#context-optional) rather than the response object.

Backing to your original question on how to access query parameters in the app router, you can achieve this using either of the following methods:

#### 1:

```js
const searchParams = req.nextUrl.searchParams;
const id = searchParams.get("id");
```

#### 2:

```js
const { searchParams } = new URL(request.url);
const id = searchParams.get('id');
```

Comment: I tried this but I was missing searchparams.get. Now this is working Thanks.